# How to pass down info to all pages in Umbraco

Tags: c#, xslt, umbraco

How does the info used in master template as `umbraco` items get passed down to child templates?

```
Master template
        Child template 1
        Child template 2
```

In `Master template` I have

```
<umbraco:Item field="training" runat="server" />
```

The field `training` is text that is entered in `umbraco`'s content tab. This info needs to be entered once and displayed in page placeholders that use Child `template 1 and 2`.

Answer (score 2):

If the doctype of the master template contains this training field, the value can be picked up in the nodes that use child templates - using the recursive options.

I've done this with macros, where to get the training item in a child (but set in the master) you use the '$' prefix (http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/templates/umbracomacro-element/macro-parameters/advanced-macro-parameter-syntax):

```
<umbraco:macro alias="macroAlias" parm1="[$training]" runat="server"/>
```

Recursive items are less often done (I don't know if I've ever used this technique - it is more common to use a macro containing razor/ascx or xslt for repeated content).  In this case you want to pick up a recursive item value (http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/xslt-useful-tips-and-snippets/settings-in-root-node-and-value-from-recursive-search) so you'd use:

```
<umbraco:Item field="training" recursive="true" runat="server"></umbraco:Item>
```

In both cases umbraco will check the current node for the value, before looking at parents.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I hardcode text into my master template, your solution works, but if I use "<umbraco:Item field="training" runat="server" />" IN THE MASTER, it will not be passed down to the child templates.

Comment: @JeftLebowski You're right it looks upwards through the structure until it finds a value (you could have many layers of inherited masterpages, not just two).

Comment: @amelvin, Hi i am using macro: <umbraco:Macro ID="Macro5" recursive="true" LatestProjectdetails="[#projectSection]" Alias="Latest-Project" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>. here projectSection is my property and i want to pass this property from  parent so that i have used a keyword called recursive but it's not working with the macro while it's working with <umbraco:Item field="projectSection" recursive="true" runat="server" />. can you suggest me on this plz.

Comment: @cracker [#projectSection] will use a parameter on the macro or page itself; [$projectSection] will look up for the property on an ancestor node if there isn't a matching one on the macro or page (ie recursively).  The difference is between '$' and '#' as the property prefix.  HTH.